# Trying to upload image to a folder and save its location in DB error

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error and I do not know why.

Upload form

```
<?php
require_once 'processor/dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_FILES['image']['name'])
    {
      $save_path="newimages"; // Folder where you wanna move the file.
      $myname = strtolower($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); //You are renaming the file here
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $save_path.$myname); // Move the uploaded file to the desired folder
    }

    $hl = $_POST['headline'];
    $fd = $_POST['feed'];
    $st = $_POST['story'];
    $tp = $_POST['type'];

    if($user->send($h1,$fd,$st,$tp,$save_path,$myname))
    {
        echo 'Success';
        $user->redirect("input.php");
    }
}
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="headline">
   <input type="text" name="feed">
   <textarea cols="15" id="comment" name="story" placeholder="Message" rows="10"></textarea>
   <input type="text" name="type">
   <input type="file" name="image">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my SEND function

```
public function send($hl,$fd,$st,$tp,$save_path,$myname)
{
  try
  {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO news(headline,feed,story,type,folder,file)
        VALUES(:headline, :feed, :story, :type, :foler, :file);
    ");

    $stmt->bindparam(":headline", $hl);
    $stmt->bindparam(":feed", $fd);
    $stmt->bindparam(":story", $st);
    $stmt->bindparam(":type", $tp);
    $stmt->bindparam(":folder", $save_path);
    $stmt->bindparam(":file", $myname);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

And finally, Here is my Error.

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(newimages//var/tmp/phpyctf0k) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c11/h05/mnt//domains/concept/html/input.php on line 12

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/var/tmp/phpyctf0K' to 'newimages//var/tmp/phpyctf0k' in /nfs/c11/h05/mnt//domains/concept/html/input.php on line 12
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

Yes I did create a new folder named newimages as well.

Comment: Look at the result from `$save_path.$myname` => `newimages//var/tmp/phpyctf0k`. You need to change `$myname = strtolower($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);` **to** `$myname = strtolower($_FILES['image']['name']);` as you want the `$_FILES['image']['name']` **not** the `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`

Comment: Issue #2 - In your query you have placeholder `:foler`, but you are binding `:folder`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

so you're saying you've made a folder in the same *relative* directory of the current running php script called `newimages`, in which you want to upload this file. just to be absolutely clear, this is not an *absolute* path, and that's OK.

```
$save_path="newimages";
```

I think it needs a trailing slash, as it appears in your output, but not in your example code.

```
$save_path="newimages/";
```

on this line, you are making the whole path and filename to lowercase of the temporary file in your *absolute* path `/var/tmp/phpyctf0k`

```
$myname = strtolower($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); //You are renaming the file here
```

so on this line, you are **appending** the local *relative* path `newimages` with the whole *absolute* path of the temp file `/var/tmp/phpyctf0k`, so this now indicates to the PHP interpreter that you intend to move a file to a directory that doesn't exist `newimages/var/tmp/phpyctf0k`

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $save_path.$myname); // Move the uploaded file to the desired folder
```

in order to fix it, you could use something like [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $save_path.basename($myname)); // Move the uploaded file to the desired folder
```

or perhaps `$_FILES['image']['name']` as @Sean commented.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $save_path.strtolower($_FILES['image']['name'])); // Move the uploaded file to the desired folder
```

Comment: After doing the changes I recieved this error.. SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: so did you eliminate either `$save_path` or `$myname`?

Comment: Well whats weird is tried what Sean said.... It still gives me the error invalid parameter.. But it DOES save the image into the folder.. It does not save anything into the DB though.

Comment: @kevinm1990112qwq your DB query `invaild parameter` issue is because in your query you have `:foler` but you are binding `:folder`. Basic typo error

Comment: @Sean One more question... When it saves the image name in my database it saves it as /var/tmp/phpdmnivo... but in my folder its named sp1.jpg

Comment: @Sean so yea, its not saving it in the folder with the created tmp name... its saving it as the actual name. If I change it to tmp_name it shoots an error